# Customize TableviewCell depending on section

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsindexpath

How do I customize the background image of a `UITableViewCell` depending on the section, they are in? E.g. in section one, the cells are supposed to have a green .png image as a background image, whereas in section two, the cells are supposed to have a red .png image as background.

Answer (score 2):

**See [Populating the Table View With Data](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10) for how to access and use section information.**

When you have more then one section you implement some optional table view source methods to deal with sections.

Then when you create cell, check in which section it is and set it up accordingly, in:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

In this method you can access `indexPath.section` and format your cell.

See [Table View Programming Guide for more](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1).

[UIKit adds property `section`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) to `NSIndexPath` so you can get `section` from index path passed in to the above method (see the first example I linked).

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
if(section == 0) {
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];


}
else if(section == 1) {

background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];

}
```